# Customize numeric keyboard in iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

I need to add cancel button in numeric keyboard. How to customize the following keyboard? When I click by cancel button, the keyboard will be hide.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Input Accessory View](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) is a view that sits on top of the keyboard. It has to the be the width of the keyboard and the height is adjustable.

On this view you could add a button, that when pressed will `ResignFirstResponder` of the `UITextField`, thus giving you the funcationality you want.

Comment: hi, i got answer... Thanks for your reply.  My answer is...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276515/customize-numeric-keyboard-in-iphone      But some issues is there.